# Repeat the column value until value change in same column value

Tags: sql-server

My table structure:

```
 declare  @TestTable as table
    (
        id int,
        somedate date,
        somevalue int
    )

    insert into @TestTable values
    (1,     '2019-01-01',   1000),
    (2,     '2019-01-02',   null ),
    (3,     '2019-01-03',   null),
    (4,     '2019-01-04',   null ),
    (5,     '2019-01-05',   800),
    (6,     '2019-01-06',   null),
    (7,     '2019-01-07',   null),
    (8,     '2019-01-08',   null),
    (9,     '2019-01-09',   null),
    (10,     '2019-01-10',   700)
```

Repeat the column value until any change  in value of column (somevalue).. Is it possible with window functions?

Required output:

[image]

Comment: i need logic for part of the code..i cant put entire code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using window function as well.
try the following:

```
select id, somevalue, newvalue=max(somevalue) over (partition by c)
from
(
    select id, somevalue
        ,c=count(somevalue) over (order by id)
    from @testtable
) t
order by id;
```

Please find the demo [**here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2a40a6815b31022e207a05968854b4c4).

Answer (score 1):

Try this below logic-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=863bad948dd4920218ce5c101b8740d5)

```
SELECT A.*,
(
    SELECT somevalue 
    FROM @TestTable 
    WHERE id = (
        SELECT MAX(id) 
        FROM @TestTable 
        WHERE id <= A.id 
        AND somevalue IS NOT NULL
    ) 
) new_column
FROM @TestTable A
ORDER BY A.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer..is it possible to do with window functions?

Comment: Window function required a value in some column to group rows. For example row 1 to 4 belongs to 1 group. Do you have any column like that? @Ajt

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [COALESCE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
.

```
SELECT
    [id]
    , somedate
    , COALESCE(somevalue, 
        (SELECT TOP (1) somevalue 
        FROM @TestTable AS p2 
        WHERE
            p2.somevalue IS NOT NULL 
            AND p2.[id] <= p.[id] ORDER BY p2.[id] DESC))
FROM @TestTable AS p;
```

Here is the live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dad68512929a1ca30b21642fa349a591) demo.

Comment: @Ajt The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60647757/10532500 is already based on the window function. To know more about window function you can refere the link https://www.sqlshack.com/use-window-functions-sql-server/.